# Account type (different from the role) in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm searching plugin to Wordpress which add one more option in account - it will be account type. For simple - i have type "gamer" and my friend has type "writer". I'm searching in Google but can't find solution.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look on this plugin 
[Custom User Roles](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members)